# Who's win in poker a's cards is 6&8 nd b's card is 10&8 nd fallen in cards 10,2,9,10,7 please give answer

Tags: rules

Who's win in poker a's cards is 6&8 nd b's card is 10&8 nd fallen in cards 10,2,9,10,7 please give answer[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

looks like your answer is in the pictures that you provided. Player A had a straight 10 high and player B had 3 10's. The winner is player A because a straight is better than 3 of a kind.

Answer (score 0):

The best hand one can make with 5 cards determines the winning hand

Player A:
10-9-8-7-6 is the best five-card hand that can be made
This is a straight

Player B:
10-10-10-9-8 is the best five-card hand that can be made
This is three of a kind (trips) with a 9 kicker

straight > three of a kind